# Return all rows from table one even if table two is empty or partial results found

Tags: php, mysql, api-eveonline

I am trying to return all the results from table one, AKA **ship_skill_tree**, while matching up the rows found in table two, AKA **character_sheet_skills**, even if the rows do not exist in table two.

```
SELECT c.`level` , t.`skillLevel` AS levelNeeded, i.`typeName`
FROM  `ship_skill_tree` t
LEFT JOIN  `character_sheet_skills` c ON t.`skillTypeID` = c.`typeID`
LEFT JOIN `invTypes` i ON i.`typeID` = t.`skillTypeID`
WHERE t.`shipTypeID` = 11176 AND c.`character_id` = 1;
```

Table One Data:

```
|shipTypeID|shipGroupID|skillTypeID|skillLevel
______________________________________________
|11011|26|3332|1
|11129|31|3327|1
|11132|31|3327|1
|11134|31|3327|1
|11172|830|3328|5
|11172|830|12093|1
|11174|893|3328|5
|11174|893|28615|1
|11176|831|3330|5
|11176|831|12092|1
```

Table Two Data:

```
|character_id|typeID|skillpoints|level|published
______________________________________________
|1|3300|1415|2|1
|1|3301|8000|3|1
|1|3327|256000|5|1
|1|3330|2829|2|1
|1|3340|181020|4|1
|1|3341|1024000|5|1
|1|3342|32000|3|1
|1|3343|32202|3|1
|1|3380|256000|5|1
|1|3385|256000|5|1
|1|3386|256000|5|1
|1|3392|256000|5|1
|1|3394|90514|4|1
|1|3402|256000|5|1
|1|3410|768000|5|1
|1|3411|135765|4|1
|1|3412|750|1|1
|1|3413|256000|5|1
|1|3416|45255|4|1
|1|3417|0|0|1
|1|3418|0|0|1
|1|3419|135765|4|1
|1|3420|181020|4|1
|1|3423|0|0|1
|1|3425|90510|4|1
|1|3426|45255|4|1
|1|3428|500|1|1
|1|3429|8000|3|1
|1|3436|45255|4|1
|1|3437|45255|4|1
|1|3438|500|1|1
|1|3449|256000|5|1
|1|3453|0|0|1
|1|3455|256000|5|1
|1|3456|226275|4|1
|1|11579|271530|4|1
|1|12186|0|0|1
|1|12187|0|0|1
|1|12188|0|0|1
|1|12190|22547|3|1
|1|12191|45255|4|1
|1|12192|45255|4|1
|1|12193|45255|4|1
|1|12195|45255|4|1
|1|16281|256000|5|1
|1|17940|1024000|5|1
|1|20342|1280000|5|1
|1|22551|40000|3|1
|1|22578|181020|4|1
|1|25739|0|0|1
|1|26252|16000|3|1
|1|26253|750|1|1
|1|26261|750|1|1
|1|32918|16000|3|1
```

invTypes table:

```
|typeID|typeName
________________
|3327|Spaceship Command
|3328|Gallente Frigate
|3330|Caldari Frigate
|3332|Gallente Cruiser
|12092|Interceptors
|12093|Covert Ops
|28615|Electronic Attack Ships
```

In the above query **shipTypeID** will always, or should always, be valid and match a record in table one, however, in table two, the rows that match may not exist.  What I need is to output as follows:

```
|level|levelNeeded|typeName
___________________________
|2|5|Caldari Frigate
|NULL|1|Interceptors
```

Currently this is what is returned:

```
|level|levelNeeded|typeName
___________________________
|2|5|Caldari Frigate
```

---

**EDIT: Solution!**

```
SELECT c.`level` , t.`skillLevel` AS levelNeeded, i.`typeName`
FROM  `ship_skill_tree` t
LEFT JOIN  `character_sheet_skills` c ON t.`skillTypeID` = c.`typeID` AND c.`character_id` = 1
INNER JOIN `invTypes` i ON i.`typeID` = t.`skillTypeID` 
WHERE t.`shipTypeID` = 11176
```

Comment: Where is `typeName` in the sample data?

Comment: JOIN conditions should be put in the `ON` clause, not the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Barmar, that was a alternate SQL, it was originally on the WHERE, I switched it to test around, I will correct in the original post.

Comment: SELECT c.`level` , t.`skillLevel` AS levelNeeded
FROM  `ship_skill_tree` t
LEFT JOIN  `character_sheet_skills` c ON t.`skillTypeID` = c.`typeID`
WHERE t.`shipTypeID` = 11176 AND c.`character_id` = 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put any restrictions on the table being joined in the `ON` clause. If you put them in the `WHERE` clause it doesn't work, because the rows that don't have any matches will produce `NULL` for those columns, and the `WHERE` clause will filter them out.

```
SELECT c.`level` , t.`skillLevel` AS levelNeeded, i.`typeName`
FROM  `ship_skill_tree` t
LEFT JOIN  `character_sheet_skills` c ON t.`skillTypeID` = c.`typeID` AND c.`character_id` = 1
LEFT JOIN `invTypes` i ON i.`typeID` = t.`skillTypeID`
WHERE t.`shipTypeID` = 11176
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb546/1)

Comment: In your demo, you have an `IS NOT NULL` check for the second table. If you're going to filter out null rows, you can just use an INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN. See [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c717f/4)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a right join or an outer join rather than a left join. Have a look through the [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) for a good overview

Comment: This is backwards. LEFT JOIN returns rows from table 1 with no match in table 2. RIGHT JOIN returns rows from table 2 with no match in table 1.